# Travelling Salesman Problem

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am trying to develop a program in C++ from Travelling Salesman Problem Algorithm. I need a distance matrix and a cost matrix. After using all the formulas, i get a new resultant matrix. But I dont understand what that matrix shows.
Suppose the resultant matrix is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Now I want to know what this matrix shows? Assume I have 3 cities to traverse.

Please tell me the flow. A sample program of this algorithm will be more favorable..
Thank you.

My Program is:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a,b,c,d,ctr,j,Q=1,K=1 ;
    float q0=0.7, p = 0.5 ;
    int phe[3][3];
    double dist[3][3] , mem[3][3],exp[3][3],eplt[3][3], rnd;
    cout<<"enter the iterations, cities , ants ";
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            dist[i][j]=(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
            if (i==j)
            dist[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<< dist[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout<<"pheromone matrix "<<endl;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
                phe[i][j]=0;
            else
                phe[i][j]=1;
        }
    }

    for ( i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for ( j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<< phe[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout<< "after iteration "<<endl;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ctr=0;
        for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            // mem[i][k]=(rand()%b)+1;
            // cout<<"memory"<<mem[i][k]<<"\n";
            rnd= (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
            cout<<"hhhhhhh"<<rnd;
            if (rnd<=q0)
            {
                cout<<"Exploitation\n";
                eplt[i][ctr] =(p*phe[i][k])+(Q/K);  
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"EXPLORATION\n";
                eplt[i][ctr]= phe[i][k]/dist[i][k];
            }
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            cout <<eplt[i][k]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    getch();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter the iterations, cities , ants 3
4
4
0       0.003967        0.335154
0.033265        0       0.2172
0.536973        0.195776        0
pheromone matrix
0       1       1
1       0       1
1       1       0
after iteration
hhhhhhh0.949919EXPLORATION
hhhhhhh0.356777EXPLOITATION
hhhhhhh0.356777EXPLOITATION
hhhhhhh0.356777EXPLOITATION
hhhhhhh0.356777EXPLOITATION
hhhhhhh0.356777EXPLOITATION
hhhhhhh0.949919EXPLORATION
```

Comment: How is what you're asking any different from the [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman) that have been asked about the traveling salesman problem?

Comment: What formulas are you referring to?

Comment: After using all the formulas I get 42.

Comment: I have a research paper which shows a algo same as TSP. I have made the following program tosolve it, but i dont know what this resultant matrix shows.

Comment: @Praful Mathur: There is no universal solution to TSP that everybody here should be aware of. Each algorithm is unique and there are dozens (not less) of them in existence. About half of them operate with various matrices. That's why it would really help if you say us how is your algorithm called or at least give us the transformation formulas.

Comment: this is definately a college homework lawl!

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about this algorithm. I only have the idea that finaaly In TSP, we find the shortest path which the salesman needs to follow in order to traverse all cities as early as possible. But i dont understand how this resultant matrix shows the minimum path.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, I'm guessing when you say `My Program` you mean `The program in the paper` since it is basically out of date C++. Standard library headers don't have `.h` appended, and `conio.h` is an MS-DOS header - most code that I've seen that uses that comes from Borland Turbo C++. Worth bearing in mind if you're going to try to compile that demo on a modern system.

Next up, what you're looking at is an adjacancy matrix. I don't believe that matrix is part of the output at all; I believe it is part of the model being used, for demonstration purposes. I believe, given you have a `pheromone` matrix, that what you're looking at here is [Ant Colony Optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization), a probabilistic method of solving the TSP and other problems that can be reduced to it.

From your output, it isn't clear where or how the result is being stored, and since this is homework, I am lazy and you're just asking for an outright answer, I'm not going to read that code. The premise of Ant Colony optimisation is that pheromone trails laid by ants, which walk the graph at random, decay over time (number of iterations). The longer it takes an ant to move along a particular vertex (distance), the more the laid pheromone decays. At this point, ants start to make decisions based on the strength of the laid pheromone along a path. So what happens is ants start to prefer certain routes over others, and continually re-inforce the pheromone along that path.

So, somewhere in there, there must be a matrix like the adjacancy matrix, storing the pheromone levels for each route. Combined with the length of the route, each iteration should detect a rate of decay.

Comment: thnx for the complete description. Now i understand what basically this algorithm is. Yes u r ryt that its an ant colony optimization. I have calculated the distance matrix and pheromone matrix.. Can you please tell me the result i am getting is showing what? I just want to know the explanation of my output.. I have used the formula for exploration and exploitation which were given to me in paper. But dont understand what actually these formula want to show.?

Comment: Nor do I, without reading the paper. I assume exploration is a method of deducing which path an ant should take based on those available and exploitation could be anything... using up some resource? That's guesswork land. I expect the final matrix is an adjacancy matrix showing you pheromone levels on paths (that being the weight) so that you can deduce the shortest path.

Comment: if you found that program in a paper you shouldn't call it your program.  and you should tell us the name of the paper, so we can look at it.  claiming it is your own work makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Your input variables a, b, c are never used.
- Your variable ctr is used in the exact same incremental way as the variable k of the same loop.
- Your phenomone matrix indicates use of an ant colony optimization algorithm, why just not say it in your question ?
- Such "iteration" should be, well, iterated, so probably the output you give us (which is not a normal output) is not the definitive solution, rather a provisory result of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In this post, implementation of simple solution is discussed.

- Consider city 1 or 0 as the starting and ending point. Since route is
  cyclic, we can consider any point as starting point.
- Generate all (n-1)! permutations of cities.
- Calculate cost of every permutation and keep track of minimum cost
  permutation.
- Return the permutation with minimum cost.

`#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`

```
int main(void){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int graph[n][n];
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<n;j++){
                scanf("%d",&graph[i][j]);
            }
        }
        vector<int> v;
        int s = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            if(i!=s){
                v.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        int ans = INT_MAX;
        do{
            int current_pathsum = 0;
            int k = s;
            for(int i = 0;i<v.size();i++){
                current_pathsum += graph[k][v[i]];
                k = v[i];
            }
            current_pathsum += graph[k][s];
            ans = min(ans,current_pathsum);
        }while(next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
}
```