# minimum amount of ascent and descent in 2d array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a 2D array of numbers, my task is to find minimum amount of ascent or descent from starting index [0,0] to the end index.

The constraint is we should not travel diagonally.

**Example:**

```
1 2 3
1 2 0
6 3 2
```

**Solution:**

```
Path --> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2.
1-1 = 0
2-1 = 1
3-2 = 1
3-2 = 1

Result = 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
```

What is the approach to solving this problem?

**Update:**

I have used [Dijstra algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/) code to pass my input 2D array and I have set `V=3` as my array has 3 rows, not sure if I have set my V value correctly.

The 2D array I have set in code is :

```
int graph[][] = new int[][] {{1,2,3}, {1,2,0},{6,3,2}};
```

Then the program gave me below result:

```
Vertex       Distance from Source
0        0
1        2
2        3
```

I am not able to understand what this result indicates, and how it relates to my problem statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003400/travelling-salesman-problem)

Comment: Nah, @jhamon, not really. Dijkstra’s algorithm might help.

Comment: Convert each node couple to their ascent/descent value, then use traveling salesman algotihm. Anyway, the question is too broad for now and should be closed.

Comment: @jhamon The traveling salesperson problem is about visiting *every* node exactly once. The solution asked for in the example is visiting just 5 of the 9 nodes. So regarding this problem as a travling salesperson problem cannot give the questioner the solution that is asked for. PS Converting each node couple to their ascent/descent value is the correct first step.

Comment: No, you have not set V, the number of vertices or nodes, correctly. You have got 9 vertices, not 3.

Comment: @OleV.V., If I use V=9, I am getting exception as `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`. I added the graph array also in updated section. Is that also wrong? I just added my array there.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem translates to finding the shortest path in a graph where your numbers are the nodes and weighted, bidirectional edges connect neighbours horizontally and vertically. The weight or distance for each edge is the ascent or descent (as @jhamon said). So your graph becomes:

```
1 -1- 2 -1- 3
|     |     |
0     0     3
|     |     |
1 -1- 2 -2- 0
|     |     |
5     1     2
|     |     |
6 -3- 3 -1- 2
```

Note that some edges have weight 0, that is, are traveled for free.

So look up an algorithm for finding the shortest path in a graph. Dijkstra’s algorithm is the obvious choice.

Or to spell it out just a little bit more: Your program will perform two steps after each other:

1. Convert your matrix to a graph where the distances between nodes are the ascents/descents. From your sample 3 by 3 array you will get a graph with 9 nodes and 12 edges.
2. Run Dijkstra’s algorithm to find the shortest distance from the starting node (the node generated from index [0, 0]) to every other node of the graph. This will also make sure that the distance to the end is calculated. This distance is the minimum amount of ascent or descent.

**Link:** [Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm | Greedy Algo-7](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/) on GeeksforGeeks

Comment: I have gone through the link, but I am not able to relate to my problem statement, when I substituted my array in the code given in above link, it gave some result which I am not able to understand, I have updated my post with what I have tried, can you please check once.

Comment: I am sorry, and it’s no attempt to be rude, it seems to me that there is a long way from what you have got to a full implementation of Dijkstra’s algorithm for you 2D array. Too long for a Stack Overflow answer to spell out. If you understand how my graph relates to your 2D array, it’s probably easier to use the graph as a starting point rather than the array, since Dijkstra’s algorithm works on a graph. You may also search for other descriptions of Dijkstra’s algorithm, there are plenty out there, and see whether it helps.